# Swift • How to implement Peek and Pop Functionality in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, contextmenu

I am currently trying to implement `Peek and Pop`  Functionality to my App.

Here is my Code so far:

```swift
NavigationView(destination: DetailView()) {
    Text("Check out the Detail View")
}
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: { // ... }) {
        Text("Option 1")
    }
    Button(action: { // ... }) {
        Text("Option 1")
    }
}
```

When long-pressing the View now, the `Context Menu` appears with the two Options.

**However, I also would like to present a Preview of the Detail View above the Options. How can I achieve this in SwiftUI?**

---

*This is an example of the final Goal:*

[image: Example]

Comment: I spent some time looking for this feature a few months ago and I couldn't find a way to provide a custom view as the provider. Maybe we'll get it on SwiftUI 3?

Comment: You could use your DetailView inside the contextMenu

Comment: @davidev Thanks for your answer. However, this is not working. Only some of the text gets displayed in a very weird format.